# Firefox started by Selenium ignores the display created by pyvirtualdisplay

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, pyvirtualdisplay

I start a display with `pyvirtualdisplay` before creating my `WebDriver` instance. If I use Chrome, it works without any problem: Chrome shows up in the Xephyr instance that `pyvirtualdisplay` creates. However, when I use Firefox, the Xephyr instance appears but Firefox shows up outside of it.

Here is code that fully reproduces the problem:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxBinary
import pyvirtualdisplay

binary = FirefoxBinary()

with pyvirtualdisplay.Display(visible=True):
    if True:  # Set to False to use Chrome...
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(None, binary)
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    driver.quit()
```

The code above is a minimal version of code that is more complex (which explains the seemingly useless `FirefoxBinary()`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Solution

Move your creation of the `FirefoxBinary` object inside the context managed by `pyvirtualdisplay.Display`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxBinary
import pyvirtualdisplay

with pyvirtualdisplay.Display(visible=True):
    if True:  # Set to False to use Chrome...
        binary = FirefoxBinary()
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(None, binary)
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    driver.quit()
```

#### Explanation

The problem is what happens behind the scenes. The environment variable named `DISPLAY` is what determines where Firefox and Chrome will connect to. It is not set in the way you'd expect it to be set.

Here is what happens with your code:

1. You create an instance of `FirefoxBinary`. If you read the source code, you'll see that when an object of this class is created **it makes a copy of `os.environ` (the environment)**.
2. You create a display with `pyvirtualdisplay.Display` and use it as a context manager. As you enter the context, the display alters `os.environ` so that as long as the context is in effect, the `DISPLAY` environment variable is set so that X clients will connect to the new display instead of what `DISPLAY` was *before* the context came into effect.
3. You create your driver. When you use Chrome, everything is fine because Chrome will get its `DISPLAY` variable from the modified environment. However, when you use Firefox, it will use the `DISPLAY` environment **from the environment that was copied in the first step.** This environment contains a value of `DISPLAY` which is *prior* to the alteration described in the previous step, so it does not connect to the new display you created.

Comment: I am so happy to have found this answer. I was trying to test multiple Firefox browsers inside of multiple display instances. Once a second display was instantiated instantiating an instance of selenium.webdriver.Firefox would throw an exception. Inside the Firefox log it would say that it could not connect to a display `:xxxx` where xxxx was not the same value as the current display. I set `os.environ['DISPLAY']` to the same value as that of the display instance before instantiating Firefox and all worked as expected.