# Splinter/Selenium running on Flask / Uwsgi does not see headless display

Tags: python, selenium, flask, headless, xvfb

So here's my setup:

Using a flask server with uwsgi, and through a controller action, calling a python script that uses splinter (which uses selenium) to automate the gui. The web server doesn't have a display, so I'm using xvfb.

Sshing into the machine and running xvfb and exporting `display=:99`, and then running the python script works great. But running it through a controller action does not work - I get the following error:

> WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect.

(this is the same error that is returned when xvfb isn't running)

`ps aux` shows that xvfb is running as the same user as the web server (I've isolated everything, and have a separate controller action that executes:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("Xvfb :99 &", stdout=fstdout,stderr=fstderr, shell=True))
```

and `DISPLAY` is set to `:99` on both root and the web server user.

I could install vncserver and try that, but I suspect I will end up with the same problem. I've also tried to avoid calling xvfb directly and using PyVirtualDisplay instead, but same problem.

edit: it errors on this line (if using splinter):

```
browser = Browser()
```

or, if selenium:

```
with pyvirtualdisplay.Display(visible=True):

    binary = FirefoxBinary()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(None, binary)
```

(it errors on the last line there)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include in your question your Selenium script, at least up to the point where the problem occurs. Otherwise, we're guessing.

Comment: I don't technically use Selenium directly--instead, I use splinter, and it errors here: browser = Browser() (which sets up the firefox selenium webdriver)

Comment: Sounds like you ran into the issue I've [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202131/firefox-started-by-selenium-ignores-the-display-created-by-pyvirtualdisplay).

Comment: Interesting idea--I tried it, and it freezes--this is a separate issue that I left out to make things simpler, but if I use PyVirtualDisplay or even subprocess.popen (xvfb) in the same script in which I will later do the gui automation, it just hangs, and even restarting uwsgi does nothing--i have to reboot the webserver entirely to be able to interact with it again.

edit--I did also try executing a separate thread before running PyVirtualDisplay or popen--and have also tried that with running the app using     app.run(threading=True)

Comment: edit #2: after rebooting, i isolated anything else that may be going on, and just used your idea (without executing xvfb independently etc)--this fixed the freezing, but I'm still left with "WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. ", which fails on "   driver = webdriver.Firefox(None, binary)"

Comment: Any other ideas? Sorry to bug.

Comment: Nope and the reason I do not have any other ideas is in my first comment.

Comment: Hi Louis--I appreciate your help--it errors on this line "browser = Browser()" or if you'd prefer, with pyvirtualdisplay.Display(visible=True): binary = FirefoxBinary() driver = webdriver.Firefox(None, binary) (it errors on driver = webdriver.Firefox(None, binary) there)--assume these are at the beginning of the script (edit--I added to original question to make it easier)