# python-selenium-chromedriver not launching any visible window

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running Python3,Django with selenium on Ubuntu.

I am trying to one a URL and login. This is my code:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
 import os
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
 from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

  display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
  display.start()

  chromedriver = "/tmp/chromedriver"
  os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

  service_log_path = "/tmp/chromedriver.log"
  service_args = ['--verbose']
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,service_args=service_args,service_log_path=service_log_path)
  driver.get(url)
  driver.implicitly_wait(5)
  password = driver.find_element_by_name('pass')
```

However, when I run the program, I get below exception:

**Exception Value:

Message: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.157)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Linux 3.13.0-53-generic x86_64)**

Above tells me that it is not able to locate the element id 'pass' that I am trying to find. But on Ubuntu box, i do not see any Chrome window pop up. It seems like it is doing this in background. How can make it launch a visible window so that I can troubleshoot?

=======

Update:
Just noticed that when my framework opens a new chrome window, its owner is apache (www-data).

```
root@ubuntu:# ps -ax | grep chrome             
 5729 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable-logging --log-level=0 --test-type=webdriver --enable-deferred-image-decoding --lang=en-US --user-data-dir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.jrPfBd --v8-natives-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd --extension-process --enable-webrtc-hw-h264-encoding --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --enable-pinch-virtual-viewport --enable-delegated-renderer --num-raster-threads=2 --gpu-rasterization-msaa-sample-count=8 --use-image-texture-target=3553 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --disable-webrtc-hw-encoding --disable-gpu-compositing --channel=5640.2.1387090022

root@ubuntu:# ls -ld /proc/5729
dr-xr-xr-x 9 www-data www-data 0 Aug 24 12:09 /proc/5729
```

This could probably the reason why I am not seeing the chrome window pop up. Any idea how to specify username that will open chrome window instance?

Comment: Can you add the HTML for the elements you're trying to find to the question? The original exception may be just that you are using the wrong locator to find an element. Doesn't hurt to double-check.

Comment: I understand that page may not contain the element id. But i want to see the page opening so that I can see what is there and what is not.

Comment: Understandable - it is a good question!

Answer (score 0):

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
```

should be

```
display = Display(visible=1, size=(800, 600))
```

Basically, [the opposite of instructions to run headless testing](http://kiennt.com/blog/2012/06/29/using-selenium-with-headless-browser.html).

Comment: I tried it, but got "Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally".

Comment: @jincept Can you get a more verbose debugging message? It might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424737/message-uunknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally

Comment: Does it work if you use visible=True instead of 0/1?

Comment: I'm basing this off the documentation here: http://ponty.github.io/PyVirtualDisplay/usage.html --- BUT! This answer may actually be more relevant to the issue you're having now that you know how to change visible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202131/firefox-started-by-selenium-ignores-the-display-created-by-pyvirtualdisplay